# Javascript Bookmarklet If-Else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I'm trying to write a bookmarklet that detects if the user is on an already parsed page and if he isn't values should be passed along to an API.

```
if (window.location.indexOf("thequeue.org") >= 0) {
    alert("Drag the Bookmarklet in your Brookmarks Bar!");
} else {
    location.href = 'http://thequeue.org/r?id=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '&title=' + document.title;
}
```

There are few tutorials on Bookmarklets in general, but I have found this conversion tool: http://jasonmillerdesign.com/Free_Stuff/Instant_Bookmarklet_Converter, which gave me this:

```
javascript:(function(){if(window.location.indexOf(%22queue.org%22)%20%3E%3D%200)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22your%20url%20contains%20the%20name%20franky%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0Alocation.href%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fthequeue.org%2Fr%3Fid%3D'%2BencodeURIComponent(location.href)%2B'%26title%3D'%2Bdocument.title%3B%0A%7D}());
```

However the bookmarklet stops working completely. I can confirm that this works: `javascript:location.href='http://thequeue.org/r?id='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&title='+document.title;`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
javascript:(function(){if(location.href.indexOf("thequeue.org/")>=0){alert("Drag the Bookmarklet in your Brookmarks Bar!");}else{location.href='http://thequeue.org/r?id='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&title='+document.title;}})();
```

Notice that i changed the if sentence slightly to make it more robust.

Comment: Thank you, worked great! I only had to change the double to single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try stripping out all the whitespace first. I don't know if that's your problem, but it will at least make your bookmarklet a lot less ugly.